# Construction of a certain long exact sequence

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a noetherian ring (not necessarily commutative) or for simplicity even a finite dimensional algebra over a field.
Let $X$ and $U$ be finitely generated $A$-modules and let $add(U)$ be the subcategory consisting of finite direct sums of direct summands of $U$.

Assume there exists a (possibly infinite) exact sequence of the form:

$$0  \rightarrow X \rightarrow U_0 \rightarrow U_1 \rightarrow U_2 \rightarrow \cdots $$
with $U_i \in add(U)$.

Assume furthermore that for each $i \geq 0$ there exist exact sequences of the form
$$0  \rightarrow U_i \rightarrow P_0^i \rightarrow P_1^i \rightarrow P_2^i \rightarrow  \cdots P_{n-1}^i  $$ with projective modules $P_j^i$, meaning that $U_i$ is an $n$-th syzygy module.

> Question: Can we construct an explicit exact sequence from the $P_j^i$ such that there is an exact sequence of the following form
> $$0 \rightarrow X' \rightarrow T^0 \rightarrow T^1 \rightarrow T^2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow  T^{n-1} \rightarrow 0$$
> with $T^i$ projective and X being a direct summand of X' (or possibly X=X')?

This is clearly possible for $n=1$, but not so clear for higher $n$.
Maybe there is a standard result in homological algebra implying this with a nice reference. Maybe there is also a simple counterexample for $n=2$.